# On Hover .li-hover not showing .sub-cat-1

Tags: javascript, html, css

On Over on the .li-hover it suppose to show a .sub-cat-1 which it is not showing. I tried several ways to make it displayed but it is not simple not showing anything in and according to css property a white box should be displayed.

Tried this html CSS

```css
categ-list
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 755px;

    padding: 10px 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}





.li-hover i
{
    
    float: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.li-hover
{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 0px 7px 21px;
    max-height: 38px;
    min-height: 21px; 
}

.li-hover a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #646464;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.li-hover a:hover
{
    color: #FF6A00;
}

.li-hover:hover
{
    width: 378px;
    max-height: 38px;
    min-height: 21px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px 1px 5px transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 1px 5px transparent;
    box-shadow: -2px 1px 5px #DCDEE3;
    
    
    border-top-color: rgb(220, 222, 227);
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
   
    border-bottom-color: rgb(220, 222, 227);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: rgb(220, 222, 227);
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    background-color: white;

    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.li-hover:hover i
{
    color: #FF6A00;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}



.li-hover-all a
{
    
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;

    padding-top : 10px;

    padding-right : 0px;

    padding-bottom : 5px;

    padding-left : 21px;
    
    
}

.sc-hd-categories:hover .categ-content
{
    display: block;
}

.sub-cat-1
{
    
    width: 600px;
    height: 755px;

    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-left: 395px;

    border: 1px solid #DCDEE3;
    border-top-color: rgb(220, 222, 227);
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: rgb(220, 222, 227);
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(220, 222, 227);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: rgb(220, 222, 227);
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    background-color: white;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -1px;

    z-index: 1;
}


.li-hover .sub-cat-1
{
    
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

.categ-list .li-hover:hover .sub-cat-1
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="categ-list">
                    <ul>
                        <div class="li-hover">
                            <li><a href="#">Machinery</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;<a href="#">Vehicles & Accessories</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            
                            
                                <div class="sub-cat-1">
                                   

                                </div>
                            
                            
                            </li>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        

                        <div class="li-hover">
                            <li><a href="#">Consumer Electronics</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;<a href="#">Home Appliances</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
                        </div>

                        

                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have your `.li-hover` class which has an `overflow: hidden` property. This meanse that everything outside the specified height and width of `.li-hover` will be *overflowing* the box and will not be shown.

Your `.sub-cat-1` element is trying to position itself in a bunch of ways. It has a `position: absolute` so it is relative to the flow of the closest relative parent. But it's the positioning with `margin-left: 395px` that makes this element jump all the way to the right and outside of the box of the `.li-hover` element.

So in conclusion. Your code actually worked, but you were hiding it from yourself.

```css
categ-list {
  width: 400px;
  height: 755px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.li-hover i {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.li-hover {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 0px 7px 21px;
  max-height: 38px;
  min-height: 21px;
}

.li-hover a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #646464;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.li-hover a:hover {
  color: #FF6A00;
}

.li-hover:hover {
  width: 378px;
  max-height: 38px;
  min-height: 21px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 1px 5px transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 1px 5px transparent;
  box-shadow: -2px 1px 5px #DCDEE3;
  border-top-color: rgb(220, 222, 227);
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(220, 222, 227);
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-color: rgb(220, 222, 227);
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-image-source: initial;
  border-image-slice: initial;
  border-image-width: initial;
  border-image-outset: initial;
  border-image-repeat: initial;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.li-hover:hover i {
  color: #FF6A00;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.li-hover-all a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 21px;
}

.sc-hd-categories:hover .categ-content {
  display: block;
}

.sub-cat-1 {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #DCDEE3;
  border-top-color: rgb(220, 222, 227);
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: rgb(220, 222, 227);
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(220, 222, 227);
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-color: rgb(220, 222, 227);
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-image-source: initial;
  border-image-slice: initial;
  border-image-width: initial;
  border-image-outset: initial;
  border-image-repeat: initial;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.li-hover .sub-cat-1 {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.li-hover:hover .sub-cat-1 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="categ-list">
  <ul>
    <li class="li-hover">
      <a href="#">Machinery</a>
      <span> / </span>
      <a href="#">Vehicles & Accessories</a>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
      <span class="sub-cat-1">Tools</span>
    </li>

    <li class="li-hover">
      <a href="#">Consumer Electronics</a>
      <span> / </span>
      <a href="#">Home Appliances</a>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Also, make sure that your HTML is valid. `<li>` elements should always be a child of either `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

This is invalid HTML:

```
<ul>
  <div>
    <li></li>
  </div>
  <div>
    <li></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

This is valid HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

You also seem to use a lot of oldschool techniques, like `float: right`. Not that there is anything wrong with it, but nowadays we have much more powerful (and predictable) tools like [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) to make great layouts. Just a tip for you to help you get further.